# error running MPI job on cluster

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, infiniband

I am running a code which works perfectly on the cluster,
As I increase the number of cores to 3844, I get the following error,

"too many retries sending message to 0x0040:0x00152080, giving up"

Is this error a network problem? or is this related to the code?

I can not post the entire code here unfortunately as it is pretty big

Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to sufficient cores? I assume that you're using qsub to send the job to the cluster, are there limits to the number of cores/machines that you can ask for

Comment: Yes, the limit is much bigger than what I am requesting for, slurm rejects submission that are above the allowed limit

Comment: Are you the administrator of this cluster? If you are not you probably want to talk to them, if you are, I would recommend asking on https://serverfault.com/ with much more information about your installation. Stackoverflow is about programming/code - and this does not appear to be a programming issue.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was not aware of serverfault.com,